# Removing Users from all AD Groups based on CSV File

Tags: powershell, activedirectorymembership

Hi I am new to PowerShell, I have a CSV file of Active directory user names, I need to remove them from all their group memberships except the default "Domain Users"

I have this script but it doesn't work, and wondering if any one could advise me on what I am doing wrong.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = import-csv C:\temp\AD\groups_test.csv

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user| foreach {Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -Members $user -Identity 
Confirm:$false}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what "doesn't work" - what happens when you run your script? :)

Comment: I get the following error, 
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\temp\AD\Remove-ADUsers6.ps1:4 char:32
+ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user| foreach {Remove-ADGroupMember $ ...
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership

Comment: Alright, so maybe you want to move your arguments around so that `$_` follows `-Identity`, in order to resolve the error: `Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user -Identity $_ -Confirm:$false` :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made the change but still getting the same error, in the CSV file, does it need a column header? also what should I be using to identify the account?  displayName, distinguishedName, sAMAccountName or userPrincipalName, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CSV has a column `SAMAccountName` with the user's username, do this:

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\temp\AD\groups_test.csv

foreach($user in $users){
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SAMAccountName |Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user.SAMAccountName -Confirm:$false
}
```

PowerShell will automatically bind the `ADGroup` objects output by `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to `Remove-ADGroupMember`'s `-Identity` parameter.

Comment: That's great it worked on my test file, thankyou so much.